# Which encryption library is used here

Tags: java, encryption

I have a **settings.ini** file which contains following text-

```
[Settings]
IP=LF5ITzfFWttFqp1JwS3yig==
DATABASE=3Oulto+YrEerz3//yLacbEYGlcue8+kv41dAyqHxxKI=
USER=mEjikdSuE2+78JsA7atxhw==
PASSWORD=kXnsw31pVdtj+LU9vZ7qPQ==
```

I know that a JAVA application reads this configuration and process it by decrypting it. Please can anyone help me find out what **library** of **JAVA** can be used to decrypt this kind of text or what library is used for this kind of encryption.

Comment: comment should be appreciated in case of down vote

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is impossible to determine which algorithm or library produced this output, because ciphertexts and hash outputs are supposed to be indistinguishable from random noise and there are *infinitely* many of them. We're not here to play the [guessing game](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not a lot of information to go on there.

- The data is base64-encoded (recognizable by the alphabet used and the `==` padding at the end), but it appears to be encrypted underneath because it decodes to what appears to be random binary data.
- The "IP", "USER", and "PASSWORD" fields are 16 bytes long, which suggests that we're looking at a symmetric cipher with a 128-bit block size and that it's using a fixed IV and no message integrity check.  (A 64-bit cipher with either an IV block or a MAC block is also possible but less likely because that would require the plaintext to be at most 8 bytes; while it's not unreasonable for usernames and passwords to be 8 bytes or less, how often does someone use integer notation for an IP address rather than dotted-decimal?)
- The "DATABASE" field is 32 bytes long, which is consistent with the hypothesis of a 128-bit block cipher with a fixed IV and no integrity check.

A 128-bit block cipher is most likely AES.  A fixed IV with no integrity check (which is an insecure cryptographic practice) suggests ECB mode.  (Technically speaking, ECB mode doesn't use an IV at all.)  But the only way to get the key will be to examine the software that uses this data.  If you disassemble it, you should be able to get both the key and confirm how the encryption was performed.

As for software to use, there are various cryptographic libraries for Java that can decrypt AES-ECB.  Try looking at the `javax.crypto` classes.  Or the Bouncycastle library.